# Jquery Retrieve Value from Dynamic looped input with same class?

Tags: jquery

Jquery : 3.x, Tomcat7

Problem :

```
var htmlStr
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){           
  htmlStr += "<input  class='my_button' type='button' data-value='"      
  + data[i].value + "' value='" + data[i].value + "'/>";                
}

$("#keyvals").html(htmlStr);

$('.my_button').click(function(){
    alert(this.data-value);
});
```

Question : For the dynamically created 'input with same class as class='my_button' , How to get the value on clicked ?

Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.data` is a function, the name of the data element is the argument. It's also a jQuery function, so you need to use `$(this)`.

```
$('.my_button').click(function(){
    alert($(this).data('value'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.my_button').click(function(){
    alert($(this).data('value'));
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/NotABlueWhale/xb838mdz/

Comment: Sorry Nope even this did not work .....  I need the value of the 'data-value'  only on click of the i/p type....

Comment: It works for me. I'll add a working JSFiddle example so you can see it in action.

Comment: Witha few tweeks "$("#keyvals").on("click",".my_button",function(){"   was bale to do the required functionality ...thx 2 cents from me...

Answer (score 0):

A dash (`-`) is not valid in a JS variable, it is seen as a minus

You can do

- `alert(this.getAttribute("data-value")); // DOM`
- `alert($(this).attr("data-value")); // jQuery`
- `alert($(this).data("value")); // jQuery DATA`

However you **MAY** also want/need to delegate since the button is dynamically generated

```
$("#keyvals").on("click",".my_button",function(){
```

[Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

```js
var data = [{value: "ONE"}, 
            {value: "TWO"}, 
            {value: "THREE"}], 
  htmlStr="";
 
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  htmlStr += "<input  class='my_button' type='button' data-value='" +
    data[i].value + "' value='" + data[i].value + "'/>";
}

$("#keyvals").html(htmlStr);

// this works without delegation because it is after the insertion 
$('.my_button').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr("data-value"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="keyvals"></div>
```

Comment: He doesn't need to delegate because he's adding the event listener after he adds the HTML.

Comment: Can whoever downvoted this answer please tell me why?

Comment: It's generally a waste of time asking that. Downvoters don't usually come back, so they'll never see the question. Your comment got sent to me because I was the last commenter.

Comment: I still need to say it. Makes me feel better ;)